# using both cte and variables to update dates in SQL

Tags: t-sql, variables, common-table-expression, row-number

I'm currently trying to implement a bit of code that will take the dates for a given list of 160ish rows and update them to be one minute after another date from the same table.

so for  example from these would go from:

```
> 1058841   2018-06-20 14:15:04.000 Copy of NtO produced
> 1058841   2018-06-14 19:58:03.000 NTO service date set to 24/05/2018

> 969565    2018-06-20 14:15:01.000 17530   Copy of NtO produced
> 969565    2018-06-14 19:58:03.000 148 NTO service date set to 24/05/2018
```

to this:

```
> 1058841   2018-06-14 19:59:03.000 Copy of NtO produced
> 1058841   2018-06-14 19:58:03.000 NTO service date set to 24/05/2018

> 969565    2018-06-14 19:59:03.000 17530   Copy of NtO produced
> 969565    2018-06-14 19:58:03.000 148 NTO service date set to 24/05/2018
```

the code I have so far:

```
declare @thisdate datetime

set @thisdate = (
select * from (
select row_number() over (partition by te_system_ref order by (select 0)) as rownumber, te_date, te_system_ref, te_event from ticket_events where te_system_ref in 
(select sl_system_ref from statutory_letter where sl_letter_batch = 9429)and te_event = 'Copy of NtO produced'
) t
where rownumber = 1
);

with rn as 
( select * from (
select row_number() over (partition by te_system_ref order by (select 0)) as rownumber1, te_date, te_system_ref, te_event from ticket_events where te_system_ref in 
(
select sl_system_ref from statutory_letter where sl_letter_batch = 9429 
)
and te_event = 'Copy of NtO produced'
) t where rownumber1 = 1)

select * from rn where te_date between dateadd(hour,1,@thisdate) and dateadd(hour,-1,@thisdate)
```

this currently gives me the error:

> Msg 116, Level 16, State 1, Line 9 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the select list when the subquery is not introduced with
>   EXISTS.

If anyone could please explain where i'm going wrong, or point me in the right direction it would be massively appreciated

Answer (score 0):

```
set @thisdate = (
select * from (
select row_number() over (partition by te_system_ref order by (select 0)) as rownumber, te_date, te_system_ref, te_event from ticket_events where te_system_ref in 
(select sl_system_ref from statutory_letter where sl_letter_batch = 9429)and te_event = 'Copy of NtO produced'
) t
where rownumber = 1
);
```

Here you try to assign several values to a scalar variable.

I guess you actually want `te_date`.

```
set @thisdate = (
select te_date from (
select row_number() over (partition by te_system_ref order by (select 0)) as rownumber, te_date from ticket_events where te_system_ref in 
(select sl_system_ref from statutory_letter where sl_letter_batch = 9429)and te_event = 'Copy of NtO produced'
) t
where rownumber = 1
);
```